# Fuzzy match by regular expression

Tags: regex, fuzzy-search

How to do a "fuzzy search" by regular expression?

For example, the text "hp laptop" might be a fuzzy match for any of:

```
xxx hp laptop
hp xxx laptop
laptop xxxxx hp
```

Comment: Try `\bhp\b.*?\blaptop\b|\blaptop\b.*?\bhp\b`. But it does not look nice, I guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use look-aheads for each word:

```
(?=.*\bhp\b)(?=.*\blaptop\b).*
```

`\b` means "word boundary", so `"bhp"` and `"laptops"` won't match.

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/yc6FUxwK3Z).

A look-ahead, which has the form `(?=...)`, asserts (but doesn't consume) that the input matches the regex (the dots `...` in this example). Because it doesn't consume input, the pointer doesn't advance when they are evaluated, so you can have multiple look-aheads at the same point.

Read [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for a far more detailed explanation.

Use as many of these look-aheads as you have words in your search query.

Comment: I should provide an anchor.

Comment: I'm ashamed to admit I never heard about look aheads in regex. Cool stuff.

Comment: awesome..how can i rewrite this in case the string is variables ?

Comment: @Bohemian Can you briefly explain how does works look aheads in the given example? EDIT: Ok, you just did, thank you very much!

Comment: @Amarnasan see edits and [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for an explanation.

Comment: @Bohemian Only a question remains... are actually needed the last two characters (dot and star) in the expression?

Comment: Also matches 'hplaptop' and 'laptop fleshpot' :)

Comment: @Lunokhod not any more :)

Comment: @Amarnasan yes you need the trailing `.*`, otherwise no input will be matched (there would be a matches, but they would be zero-width between each character pair preceding the first search word)

Comment: @AvinashRaj anchor `^` is not needed - it's implied (adding the anchor won't make any difference)

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest to test `/\bhp\b/ig` and `/\blaptop\b/ig`separately, if first passes then test the second, this is the most simple way.

This `/(\bhp\b).*(\blaptop\b)|(\blaptop\b).*(\bhp\b)/gi` will be good to test if there are both words 'hp' and 'laptop' in a string as well, but it is not very flexible.

It is necessary to use word boundaries `\b` in oder to avoid 'fleshpot' and hplaptop and so on matching.

[test](https://regex101.com/r/nE5yI6/1)